# Iterating over multidimensional PHP array, averaging value where key is the same

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like the one below but much bigger:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [carrier] => Test Carrier
        [value] => 5
    ),
    [1] => Array(
        [carrier] => New Carrier
        [value] => 18
    ),
    [2] => Array(
        [carrier] = Test Carrier
        [value] => 8
    )
)
```

In reality there are about 306 arrays with key-value pairs of carrier and value.  What I want to do, is iterate of this array above (which has multiple arrays with carrier => Test Carrier) and add the corresponding value where the carrier name is the same and then divide by 2 to achieve the average.

So for the example above, the result in pseudocode would be:

1. Code notices that carrier is the same as another (i.e. Test Carrier)
2. Adds 8 + 5 for 13, but remembers that it has 2 arrays with `carrier = Test Carrier` so it divides by 2 and sets the value equal to that.  If it happens a third time, it adds and divides by 2.  The goal is to get the average if there is 15 records with the same carrier name add all values and divide by 15.
3. Returns an array with the same data as above, but no duplicate carrier names, with the value equal to the average of all of the arrays with the same name combined.

This is what I have thus far but it's incomplete:

```
    $cars = array(
        'carriers' => array(
        )
    );

    $avgs = array();

    foreach($arr as $new) {

        if(in_array($new['carrier'], $cars['carriers'])) {

            $avgs['value'] = $avgs['value'] + $new['value'] / $cars['count'];

        } else {

            $avgs[] = $new;

            $cars['carriers'] = array(
                'carrier' => $new['carrier'],
                'count'   => 0
            );

        }

    }
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
$data = array(
    array(
        "carrier" => "Test Carrier",
        "value" => 5
    ),
    array(
        "carrier" => "New Carrier",
        "value" => 18
    ),
    array(
        "carrier" => "Test Carrier",
        "value" => 8
    )
);

$results = array();

foreach($data as $row){
    //print_r($row);
    $carrier = $row['carrier'];
    $value = $row['value'];
    if( array_key_exists ( $carrier , $results ) ){
        $results["$carrier"]["value"] =  ( ( $results["$carrier"]["count"] * $results["$carrier"]["value"] ) + $value ) / ( $results["$carrier"]["count"] + 1 );
        $results["$carrier"]["count"] = $results["$carrier"]["count"] + 1;
    }else{
        $results["$carrier"] = array("value"=>$value, "count" => 1);
    }

    //echo "Processing carrier: $carrier value: $value </br>";
}

print_r($results);
```